# Starter circuit for solar module driven pump motor

Tags: dc-motor, solar-cell, fluid-pump

I have a 24 V 100 W solar panel and a 24 V DC 50 W pump, which has a resistance of 2 Ω while at 0 rpm. The solar panel is directly connected to the pump motor.

The problem is: While the solar panel can drive the motor when it is running, it mostly fails to provide the break-away current the pump requires, so its motor more often than not fails to start turning.

Therefore I thought of a starter circuit, which stores charge in large caps and and fires (drives the pump) as soon as the voltage over the caps has reached a certain limit. Then the caps would provide more current and help starting the motor.
When the sun is blocked by clouds etc., the pump stops and the circuit should "reset", so that the caps can be charged again.

I thought of triggering a thyristor at a certain voltage, but I fear it would only reset back to non-conduction at night, since the solar panel *will* provide some current even in low-sun conditions, but not enough to keep the pump running.

So, I *think* I need kind of a custom starter circuit that "fires" when a certain voltage has accumulated across some caps, and stops conducting when the current falls under a certain limit afterwards, so that the caps can be charged again.

Starting voltage and stopping current limits would need to be adjustable, because I have no means to really measure the minimum voltage/current behavior of the pump.

How do I get a solar powered DC pump motor to start reliably?

Comment: Are you connecting the panel directly to the pump?

Comment: Ask a specific question, you'll get better results

Comment: What guaranteed current does it need to begin turning? What is the minimum votage required to get it turning? What is the full-speed load current (worst case)?

Comment: @Andyaka I do not know for sure, but it _should_ be 24 V/2 Ω = 12 A. Full speed load current is somewhere around 2 A, as it is a 50 W motor.

Comment: 2 ohm is the stalled rotor resistance and you cannot assume that the rotor resistance will "look" like this electrically when rotating because of back emfs.

Comment: @laptop2d: What you have written was already in my question, but obviously not clear enough. I hope my question is more understandable after my edit now.

Comment: @Andyaka: I _do_ not assume that. I _know_, though, that something around at least 2.5 A is required to get the pump running (much lower than the 12 A "nominal" break-away current), which proves to be rather hard to achieve under regular conditions with a 24 V, 100 V rated solar panel.

Comment: You would get better efficiency from an induction motor or PMSM than a brushed DC motor.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is your solar panel can't source that much power with that much load, look at this curve:

[image]
Source: https://arstechnica.com/civis/viewtopic.php?f=26&t=1402629

If you draw more current from the cell you get less power. People have fixed this problem long ago, you need a MPPT tracker to regulate the voltage to 24V.

The second problem is power, the motor won't start unless you have enough starting current. Make sure you size your solar system (and MPPT tracker) to have enough power for the starting current. If you need 6A of starting current, you'll need 144W of power. If it's 12A you'll need more.

Comment: I _know_ that, which is why I asked for a starter circuit, not an explanation of how solar panel power output works. And to counter your argument: I already pointed out in my question, that at times the motor _does_ start (full sun etc.pp.).

Comment: I was just trying to answer your question: ***How do I get a solar powered DC pump motor to start reliably?*** The answer, you get a MPPT tracker, you *cannot* get your motor to start without an MPPT tracker, solar modules *do not* have enough source impedance and they never will.

Comment: My panel _does_ sometimes start the motor, so "never will" does not apply. I just need a starter circuit, which makes use of caps, not a MPPT, since I do not need the panel to run at the MPP and do not want to use regular batteries. I just need a starter circuit in the aforementioned parameters; voltage and current limits I can adjust on my own, but I have some difficulty with designing a suitable circuit.

Answer (score 0):

Find out how much time the motor takes to start.  I'm guessing that it is significantly-less than a second but you need to find out.

Find out what the minimum voltage that the motor will start at.  It will be less than the normal running voltage - perhaps significantly so.

Use the numbers above to calculate an estimate of the minimum amount of capacitance that you need to place in parallel with your solar panel.  Remember that a current of 1 Amp will discharge a 1 Farad capacitor by 1 Volt in 1 second.

When you come up with the minimum amount of capacitance required, double that value (safety margin) and try it.

Comment: And how do I trigger the caps then? I am lacking a proper circuit to turn the load on, when the caps are charged (voltage-triggered) and recharge the caps, i.e turn off the load (low-current-triggered). Any ideas?